# Toolbar icons disappearing after expanding the SearchView in Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

here's my problem:

I have that nice toolbar with the icons in landscape mode:
[image]

after expanding the search view and showing the popup menu the "add" item appears (I thought that it shouldn't):

[image]

then returning with the back arrow key, as you see, the add button goes:

[image]

and you won't find it in the popup menu anymore:
[image]

I'm using support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0, and here's my menu code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:visible="true"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
    <item android:title="Add"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:id="@+id/add" />
    <item android:title="Settings"
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:visible="true" />
    <item android:title="Feedback"
        android:id="@+id/feedbvack"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_feedback"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:visible="true" />

</menu>
```

I can set the add button showAsAction to "always" but I know that this is discouraged. 
Does anyone here know why is there this behavior? and how can I prevent that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use this:

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchMenuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        //or use invalidateOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }
});
```

So when SearchView will be collapsed Toolbar will reallocate items and ifRoom items will be visible. I had this bug too and solved it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:visible="true"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
<item android:title="Add"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:id="@+id/add" />
<item android:title="Settings"
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:visible="true" />
<item android:title="Feedback"
    android:id="@+id/feedbvack"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_feedback"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:visible="true" />
```

Set `app:showAsAction` to `always` to make sure it will be visible always.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to show it always, if space is limited (ex: portrait mode in a small device) I want it it to be sent to the popup menu.

Answer (score 1):

Use of ifRoom has this feature if space available it will show or else it will hide it better use always or never

```
<item android:title="Add"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:id="@+id/add" />
```

Comment: Yes, I was just wondering why did the icon disappear after pressing the back arrow key?

Comment: but in the end there is no "add " option, neither in the toolbar nor in the popup menu?

Comment: Internally it calculates space you have three options 1.never 2.always 3.ifRoom

Comment: using always will force toolbar to show menu item everytime

Comment: I know that, and I used it just to prevent the icon from showing when space is limited, but I think I will settle for your solution and use "always",. thanks!

Comment: consider this answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

@Kovy has answered above with the fix for this bug and I confirm it fixes the bug. Thank you very much, mate! However, the above function has been deprecated in favour of individual menu items OnActionExpandListener. Example of it is as posted below:

```
MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
        }
    });
```